# Angular 2 - How to catch 401 error when calling web service

Tags: javascript, angular, try-catch

I am calling a web service by sending a user's username and password. If the wrong username and password are given, I get a 401 UNAUTHORIZED error. I would like to be able to catch when a 401 happens in order to output an error message on the screen.

Here is the code for calling the service:

```
return this.client.get<User>(this.BASEURL + 'api/id', new User(), null, encodedString)
        .map(result => {
            // If authorized, store the relevant information
            if (result) {
                result = new User().deserialize(result);
            }
            this.user.next(result);
            return result;
        }, this)
        .catch(this.handleError);
```

I attempted to use a try catch around the entire thing, but it didn't do anything (I'm guessing because of async). I also tried a console.log(result); after if(result), but I never get to the .map due to the 401 error. I'm not sure how else to approach this. Thanks!

Comment: `this.handleError` has to handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define the handleError method. have a look at the example [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#fetch-data).